# Add Mouse Wheel scrolling ability

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script which enable scrollbar within `<div>`

I want to add functionality to scroll even using "Mouse Scroll-Wheel"

Here is code :

```
var TINY={};

function T$(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function T$$$(){return document.all?1:0}

TINY.scroller=function(){
 return{
  init:function(a,c,b,s,d){
   a=T$(a); a.c=c; a.s=s; c=T$(c); b=T$(b); s=T$(s); a.n=d||0;
   b.style.display='block'; a.style.overflow='hidden';
   var h=a.offsetHeight, t=c.offsetHeight;
   if(t<h){
    b.style.display='none'
   }else{
    a.m=h-t; a.d=t/h; s.style.height=(h*(h/t))+'px'; s.style.top=b.style.top=0;
    s.onmousedown=function(event){TINY.scroller.st(event,a.id); return false};
    s.onselectstart=function(){return false}
   }
   a.l=b.offsetHeight-s.offsetHeight
  },
  st:function(e,f){
   var a=T$(f), s=T$(a.s); a.bcs=TINY.cursor.top(e); a.bct=parseInt(s.style.top);
   if(a.mv){this.sp(f)}
   a.mv=function(event){TINY.scroller.mv(event,f)};
   a.sp=function(){TINY.scroller.sp(f)};
   if(T$$$()){
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove',a.mv); document.attachEvent('onmouseup',a.sp)
   }else{
    document.addEventListener('mousemove',a.mv,1); document.addEventListener('mouseup',a.sp,1)
   }
   if(a.d){s.className+=' '+a.n}
  },
  mv:function(e,f){
   var a=T$(f), m=TINY.cursor.top(e)-a.bcs+a.bct, s=T$(a.s), c=T$(a.c);
   if(m>=0&&m<a.l){
    s.style.top=m+'px'; c.style.top=(m*-1*a.d)+'px'
   }else if(m<0){
    s.style.top=0; c.style.top=0
   }else if(m>a.l){
    s.style.top=a.l+'px'; c.style.top=a.m+'px'
   }
  },
  sp:function(f){
   var a=T$(f), s=T$(a.s); if(a.d){s.className=s.className.replace(' '+a.n,'')}
   if(T$$$()){
    document.detachEvent('onmousemove',a.mv); document.detachEvent('onmouseup',a.sp)
   }else{
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove',a.mv,1); document.removeEventListener('mouseup',a.sp,1)
   }
   a.mv=0;
  }
 }
}();

TINY.cursor=function(){
 return{
  top:function(e){
    return T$$$()?window.event.clientY+document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.body.scrollTop:e.clientY+window.scrollY
  }
 }
}();
```

How to add this ability to current code ?

Thanks.

**EDIT : Issue Solved**

Comment: That demo does not do anything interesting for me in Firefox, Chrome, or IE8. Clicking on the little arrows has no effect.

Comment: but the worst is that your code is an obfuscated mess. You really do think that someone will spend a whole day trying to figure out what `a.m` means in `mv()`??

Comment: @Pointy: arrow is just an design element. you need to click on it & pull Up/down.

Comment: That one pulled a `lol` out of me. Is that minified code? I just hope so.. I just hope it :p

Comment: Not working for me in Firefox.

Comment: Demo is working on on IE8, FF3.6, Chrome

Comment: SO is so harsh... In any case visit the creator's site and poke him about the scrollwheel he promised :) http://www.leigeber.com/2009/09/javascript-scrollable-div/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/

```
TINY.scroller=function(){

 return{
  init:function(a,c,b,s,d){
   a=T$(a); a.c=c; a.s=s; c=T$(c); b=T$(b); s=T$(s); a.n=d||0;
   b.style.display='block'; a.style.overflow='hidden';
   var h=a.offsetHeight, t=c.offsetHeight;
   if(t<h){
    b.style.display='none'
   }else{
    a.m=h-t; a.d=t/h; s.style.height=(h*(h/t))+'px'; s.style.top=b.style.top=0;
    s.onmousedown=function(event){TINY.scroller.st(event,a.id); return false};
    s.onselectstart=function(){return false}
   }


   if (window.addEventListener)   a.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(event){TINY.scroller.wheel(event,a.id); return false}, false);
    /** IE/Opera. */
    a.onmousewheel = a.onmousewheel = function(event){TINY.scroller.wheel(event,a.id); return false};

   a.l=b.offsetHeight-s.offsetHeight
  },
/** Event handler for mouse wheel event.
 */
  wheel: function (event,f){

        var delta = 0;
        if (!event) /* For IE. */
                event = window.event;
        if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */
                delta = event.wheelDelta/120;
        } else if (event.detail) { /** Mozilla case. */
                /** In Mozilla, sign of delta is different than in IE.
                 * Also, delta is multiple of 3.
                 */
                delta = -event.detail/3;
        }
        /** If delta is nonzero, handle it.
         * Basically, delta is now positive if wheel was scrolled up,
         * and negative, if wheel was scrolled down.
         */
        if (delta) {
            console.log(delta);            
            var a=T$(f), s=T$(a.s), c=T$(a.c); a.bcs=TINY.cursor.top(event); a.bct=parseInt(s.style.top);
            var m = a.bct - delta;
           if(m>=0&&m<a.l){
                s.style.top=m+'px'; c.style.top=(m*-1*a.d)+'px'
           }else if(m<0){
                s.style.top=0; c.style.top=0
           }else if(m>a.l){
                s.style.top=a.l+'px'; c.style.top=a.m+'px'
           }
        }
        /** Prevent default actions caused by mouse wheel.
         * That might be ugly, but we handle scrolls somehow
         * anyway, so don't bother here..
         */
        if (event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
    },
  st:function(e,f){
   var a=T$(f), s=T$(a.s), c=T$(a.c); a.bcs=TINY.cursor.top(e); a.bct=parseInt(s.style.top);
   if(a.mv){this.sp(f)}
   a.mv=function(event){TINY.scroller.mv(event,f)};
   a.sp=function(){TINY.scroller.sp(f)};
   if(T$$$()){
    document.attachEvent('onmousemove',a.mv); document.attachEvent('onmouseup',a.sp)
   }else{
    document.addEventListener('mousemove',a.mv,1); document.addEventListener('mouseup',a.sp,1)
   }
   if(a.d){s.className+=' '+a.n}
  },
  mv:function(e,f){
   var a=T$(f), m=TINY.cursor.top(e)-a.bcs+a.bct, s=T$(a.s), c=T$(a.c);
   if(m>=0&&m<a.l){
    s.style.top=m+'px'; c.style.top=(m*-1*a.d)+'px'
   }else if(m<0){
    s.style.top=0; c.style.top=0
   }else if(m>a.l){
    s.style.top=a.l+'px'; c.style.top=a.m+'px'
   }
  },
  sp:function(f){
   var a=T$(f), s=T$(a.s); if(a.d){s.className=s.className.replace(' '+a.n,'')}
   if(T$$$()){
    document.detachEvent('onmousemove',a.mv); document.detachEvent('onmouseup',a.sp)
   }else{
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove',a.mv,1); document.removeEventListener('mouseup',a.sp,1)
   }
   a.mv=0;
  }
 }
}();
```

Or, just create a hidden scrollbar on the left, under your scrollbar!